# Override Authorization Role For controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Default Role for all controllers configured in my global.asax

```
protected override void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     //Note: Client Authentication Filter is just a fancy AuthorizeAttribute
     config.Filters.Add(new ClientAuthenticationFilter(APIRoles.MYAPI));
}
```

This adds a requirement for a role to all controllers.  I would like to override that role for a specific controller

```
public class MFAController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(AuthAPIRoutes.GET_MFA_DEVICES)]
    [Authorize(Roles = "MyCustomRoles")]
    public MFAMethodDTO[] GetMultiFactorMethods()
    {
        return GlobalFactory<IMFASecurityService>.Instance.GetMultiFactorMethods();
    }
    //...
}
```

However when I do this. I get an error because my role original role APIRoles.MYAPI is missing.  Is there a default way to override the AuthorizationAtrributes for controllers so they take precedence over the Global Filter?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do like below. This is not exactly you want, it needs to customize.

```
public class MyAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // ...
        // if (HttpContext.Current.User == null || HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == null || !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            // throw new Exception("Not logged in");
    }
}

[MyAuthorize]
public bool DoSomthing()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was looking for a way to override the default one set by the global asax, I was hoping there was a default way to do this without coding a custom attribute, I don't see a way to do so, +1 for the attempt